# In Spring security, how do I invoke two filters upon successful login?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, filter

I’m using Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE.  I want two things to happen upon successful authentication.  Currently, I have this …

```
<beans:bean id="mycoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.mainco.myco.core.security.mycoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/failure" />
            <beans:property name="exceptionMappings" ref="exceptionMappings" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/success" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean> 
…
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.mainco.subco.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="sessionService" ref="sessionService" />
</beans:bean>

<http name="defaultSecurity" security-context-repository-ref="mycoSecurityContextRepository"
    auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    access-denied-page="/denied" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
        ref="mycoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/lti/launch" access="permitAll" />
    …
    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
</http>
```

However, upon deploying my application, I get this exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Filter beans '<springboardUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter>' and '<org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>' have the same 'order' value. When using custom filters, please make sure the positions do not conflict with default filters. Alternatively you can disable the default filters by removing the corresponding child elements from <http> and avoiding the use of <http auto-config='true'>.
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext-ebook-security.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.checkFilterChainOrder(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:272)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.createFilterChain(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.parse(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:250)
    ... 29 more
```

I cna’t find an “order” attribute in any of my filter declarations.  What is the right way to re-arrange my config above, or at least do two things at once upon login.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating my own success handler class that extended org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler, making my declaration

```
<beans:bean id="mycoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.mainco.myco.core.security.mycoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/failure" />
            <beans:property name="exceptionMappings" ref="exceptionMappings" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class=“org.mainco.subco.myproject.MyCustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler”>
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/success" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

As such, I was able to do my two things.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in given code I can see only one filter.

Try declaring your filters like:

```
<bean id="successfulAuthenticationFilters" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter">
    <property name="filters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="filter1"/>
            <ref bean="filter2"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Than just use:

```
<custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
        ref="successfulAuthenticationFilters" />
```

It will execute both your filters in place of default form login filter.

Comment: The first filter is the "authenticationSuccessHandler" property fo the bean with id "mycoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter" and the second is the "form-login authentication-success-handler-ref" declaration.  When I tried your suggestion, I got the error, “java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.mainco.subco.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler] to required type [javax.servlet.Filter] for property 'filters[1]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found”

Comment: So you're not invoking two filters, but two authenticationSuccessHandlers - you can't do that . If i understand correctly what you wanted to achieve, you use authenticationSuccessHandler to redirect to success url. Instead, remove it and change customAuthenticationSuccessHandler to redirect to "/success"

Comment: Eventually you can move the logic from customAuthenticationSuccessHandler to some new filter class (implementing Filter interface) and execute it after form login filter: `<custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customFilter" />`